# Updating Route Table in AWS via Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am new to boto3 and am creating a python script that will gather a list of IP addresses from Amazon and compare that to the current routes in one of our route tables.

I first gather all of the IPs that are tagged with CLOUDFRONT. Then I need to check if the current routes in our route table match this list. If the lists match, nothing needs to be changed. If the lists do not match, the routes with the Internet Gateway Destination need to be deleted and the new list needs to be added with all of them having the Internet Gateway as the destination.

Here is my current code:

```
def getCFIPs():
    #get json from amazon
    with urllib.request.urlopen('https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-    ranges.json') as response:
        urlData=json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8'))

    #debug output
    #print(json.dumps(urlData, indent=2))

    cfIPs=[]

    for entry in urlData['prefixes']:
        #print(json.dumps(entry, indent=2))
        if(entry['service'] == "CLOUDFRONT"):
            cfIPs.append(entry['ip_prefix'])

    #print(json.dumps(cfIPs, indent=2))

    return cfIPs

def updateRouteTables(account, tableId, gateId, desCidrBlock):
    #keep local, vgw route, and pl route
    #if routes match: keep the Same
    #if not match: delete old igw routes & add new ones

    #Connect to EC2
    ec2=boto3.client('ec2')

    #compare routes in route table with cfIPs (only with destination IGW)
    #if IGW routes match cfIPs, print "lists match"

    #if IGW routes do not match cfIPs, delete all routes with destination IGW
    delete_route(tableId, desCidrBlock, dry_run=False)

    #add routes in cfIPs to destination IGW if not matching
    ec2=client.create_route(
        DryRun=True|False,
        RouteTableId=tableId,
        DestinationCidrBlock='string',
        #InternetGateway - Search for GatewayID
        GatewayId=gateId,
        InstanceId='string',
        NetworkInterfaceId='string',
        VpcPeeringConnectionId='string'
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    cfIPs=getCFIPs()

    account = sys.argv[1]
    tableId = sys.argv[2]
    gateId = sys.argv[3]
    desCidrBlock = sys.argv[4]

    updateRouteTables(account, tableId, gateId, desCidrBlock)

    with open(repoRootDir + "\PythonUtils\AccountRoleInfo.json") as data_file:
        accounts = json.load(data_file)

    for account in accounts:
        print("Running Cloudfront Update Scan in Account: " + account)

        updateRouteTables(account, tableId, gateId, desCidrBlock)
```

I am unsure how I can grab the current routes in updateRouteTables() with the destination of the Internet Gateway and compare them to the list I get from getCFIPs(). I am also not sure if my delete_route and create_route code is correct.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: That's an awful lot of code to be showing us. Can you clarify the specific thing with which you are having difficulty? For example "How do I obtain a list of xxx?".

Comment: The getCFIPs() is just for your reference as to how I'm obtaining the list I want to compare with. I need help with the updateRouteTables(). I need to first grab a list of the current routes in a specified route table. Then compare this list of current routes with the one from getCFIPs(). If they differ, I need to delete the current routes and replace them with the new routes. I am unsure of how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code. I am matching interface list since i need to delete the route with gateway as NetworkInterfaceId(if exist) and add a new route

```
def update_route_table(self):
        client = boto3.client('ec2',self.region,config=self.retry_config)
        resp_rt_table = client.describe_route_tables(Filters=[{'Name': 'vpc-id','Values': [self.vpc_id,]},])['RouteTables']
        interface_mapping=self.merge_peer_self_eni_dict() 
        for key in interface_mapping.keys(): 
            for iter in resp_rt_table: 
                for each_route in  iter['Routes']: 
                    try:
                        if each_route['NetworkInterfaceId'] == key:
                            try:
                                client.delete_route(DestinationCidrBlock=each_route['DestinationCidrBlock'],RouteTableId=iter['RouteTableId'])
                                print "Route Deleted for "+str(each_route['DestinationCidrBlock'])+" with eniid "+str(key)
                                client.create_route(DestinationCidrBlock=each_route['DestinationCidrBlock'],NetworkInterfaceId=interface_mapping[key],RouteTableId=iter['RouteTableId'])
                                print "Route created for  "+str(each_route['DestinationCidrBlock'])+" with eniid "+str(interface_mapping[key])
                            except Exception as e:
                                print e
                    except :
                        continue
```